# How to use Google Maps API to get coordinates in applications's onPause event in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-service, onpause

I'm developing an android application as a real time tracking app to get the mealtime location updates. I can get coordinates when the google map fragment is visible in the screen. But I'm unable to get the accurate location when the application is paused.
I have included the same code which is running in the main activity also in on Pause event.
Sp how to use Google Maps API and update the map to get the correct coordinate when the app is in on Pause event.
What I discovered was that the GPS icon starts to blink when the map activity is visible in the screen. By blinking its getting the latest location update to the phone. But when I'm going to pause the app the blinking of the GPS icon will also disappear.

What I meant by on Pause event means -> Sending the application to the running applications by pressing the middle key or locking the screen of the android phone.

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    googleMap.clear();
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    String netstatus=null;
    try
    {
     latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
     longitude=myLocation.getLongitude(); 
     netstatus="success";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        showToastMessage("nogps",1000);
         netstatus="error";
    }
  } protected void onPause()
{
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a LocationListener like this

```
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.v("tag", "IN ON LOCATION CHANGE, lat=" + location.getLatitude() + ", lon=" + location.getLongitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
```

and request for new coordinates in     `onPause()` method       `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);`

also don't forget to add this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Previously I used this one. But it is not blinking the GPS icon in my phone. Is the above code segment gives the the latest location update??